# Is interior-point not supported in scipy.optimize.linprog?

Tags: python, scipy, linear-programming

I was going through the documentation for `scipy.optimize.linprog`, and noticed that there are two methods built into the function: the simplex and interior-point methods.

I also learned from experimentation that the simplex method fails due to bad handling of floating points, so I decided to use the interior-point method.

However, when I run anything like the following:

```
scipy.optimize.linprog(A_eq = A, b_eq = B, method='interior-point')
```

I get an error message informing me that interior-point is not a valid string for the parameter method. I made sure to copy the text directly from the source code of the function, and it still didn't recognize it.

Moreover, I tried to look at the source code for the interior-point method the function uses (which is [here](http://www.subfi.info/djng/bpy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_linprog_ip.py)) but I only got more lost.

Am I doing something wrong here? What should I be doing here?

## Edit

As the comments noted, my scipy version was not updated enough to use interior-point. However, the python version I'm using is built into SQL as part of sp_execute_external_script, so I'm not sure whether I can update scipy. Do I have an alternative?

Comment: What's with the `Aeq` and `beq` keywords?  I don't see those in the documentation.  Where's initial coefficients parameter?

Comment: Which version of scipy are you using?  You can check with `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`.  The interior point method was added in scipy 1.0.0.

Comment: Ah I have 0.19.1, that probably explains it.

Comment: Which SQL has Python in it?

Comment: 2017 management studio

Comment: I think that command is only calling externals. It has no control over what you call. I might be wrong but it is unlikely that Python is hard-coded into it.

Comment: [Probably relevant.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/python/install-additional-python-packages-on-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @percusse I still can't find where its installed python, so I'm not sure

Comment: @user2357112 that guide unfortunately doesn't explain how to update packages